# How to get Random Number array from Chainlink vrf

Tags: blockchain, chainlink

I want a random array of numbers without repeating element from chailink vrf.

Answer (score 1):

You can find [examples](https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-a-random-number/#analyzing-the-contract) of how to do just this in the [documentation](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf/) for Chainlink VRF